# Sending a HTTP request using python

Tags: python, http-post, fiddler, httplib

I have intercepted an HTTP request using FIDDLER.

I would like to send the same request, just this time using python and not my browser.

I did some research and found that httplib is the way to go, but for some reason my code does not work.

No request is sent from my computer (I can verify this by using FIDDLER).

Any ideas whats wrong ?

```
import httplib

headers = {
"Host":" unive.edu",
"Connection":" keep-alive",
"Content-Length":" 5142",
"Cache-Control":" max-age=0",
"Accept":" text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
"Origin":" http://unive.edu",
"User-Agent":" Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36",
"Content-Type":" application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"DNT":" 1",
"Referer":" http://unive.edu/webtixsnetglilot/SelectCoursePage2.aspx?dtticks=635358672778578750&hideBackButton=1",
"Accept-Encoding":" gzip,deflate,sdch",
"Accept-Language":" en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6",
"Cookie":" ASP.NET_SessionId=c5nch3ouzxkaaa5bk1rflaic; __atuvc=1%7C16%2C1%7C17%2C0%7C18%2C0%7C19%2C1%7C20; __utma=184162612.90089091.1384326557.1400242958.1400259831.35; __utmb=184162612.4.10.1400259831; __utmc=184162612; __utmz=184162612.1384326557.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); SS#177904#2#1#StopLoad#635358666509203750=true; SS#177904#2#1#StopLoad#635358672778891250=true; hfSKey=|||||||||gli; hfOIKey=imVrnYvw; SS#177904#2#1#StopLoad#635358677931547500=true;"
}

body = ""

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("unive.edu")
conn.request("POST", "/web/SelectCoursePage2.aspx?dtticks=635358682524828750&hideBackButton=1", None, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
```

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've got a `Content-Length` header claiming that you're going to send the server `5142` bytes in the `POST` body but you're not sending any body content at all. As a consequence, the server hangs waiting for the body; it will probably fail with a time out in a few minutes.

To fix this, ensure that the `Content-Length` header matches the length of the body in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `print(res.status)`

Otherwise what I'm using is: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Its actually stuck on "res = conn.getresponse()", it never gets to the command after it