# How can one intercept an HTTP request, stop the request, and redirect the user to another site?

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

I am working on a url redirector application, in Python. The idea of this application is simple: when a user performs an http request to a certain domain (e.g. to https://google.com), the app stops the request and performs another http request (e.g. to https://github.com), thereby redirecting the user to the second page.

Unfortunately, I have looked through SO and I haven't found any question that addresses this issue directly:

- [Intercept and filter HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890743/intercept-and-filter-http-request) doesn't redirect
- [Sending a HTTP request using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711249/sending-a-http-request-using-python) doesn't either

Admittedly, I only have some fabricated pseudocode to demonstrate what I wish to do, but it may prove useful:

```py
import requests

original_site = "https://google.com"
redirect_site = "https://github.com"

def redirect_request():
    if requests.get(original_site) == True:
        requests.kill(request.original_site.id)
        requests.get(redirect_site)
```

I greatly appreciate any suggestions.

**EDIT - Here is a clarification of what I mean:**

The user runs my python script, which I will call `foobar.py`, as follows:

```
python foobar.py
```

Then the user opens their web browser, and enters the url https://google.com, and as the script is running, the user will not actually visit https://google.com, but be redirected to https://github.com

Comment: I don't understand the context here.  If the user types google.com into their browser, how is your code going to "intercept" that request?  Are you assuming they have installed some program of yours?

Comment: @JohnGordon That is correct, I am assuming that they are going to run the script from the command line e.g. `python myscript.py` and then opens their browser to type https://google.com

Comment: You probably want something like a browser plugin. Otherwise you can't make the browser do something like that. Or you can mess with the hosts file & do a DNS redirect there.

Comment: What about using selenium and injecting some javascript that does the redirect? Because I am trying to keep it just as a python script, not a browser plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is if you are trying to build a lightweight web app using python where you can mess with HTTP redirects, you can use Flask to accept a GET on a route and then simply do a redirect.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect("https://www.google.com")
```

But to answer your question more directly, you don't "stop" the initial request. You simply find a way to handle it and serve back a response that you specify.

Comment: Note this only redirects `http://localhost:8080` to google.com

Comment: It will redirect from whatever domain the app is served on. If you serve on localhost:XXXX it will work there too.

Comment: Which more than likely will be localhost given the OP wants users to run his script locally.

Comment: @SamYi I would like to redirect not just localhost, but any given domain.